# Passport isAuthenticated return false after successRedirect

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I'm a beginner of coding.
I'm trying to build an authentication system with passport-local.
When I entered the correct email and password, the passport.authenticate succeed, to make sure that I use `console.log(req.user)` to make sure that it exist and it sure did.
However, after the successRedirect, the req.user isn't existed in the req.
Also, the req.isAuthenticated() return false.
Have anyone face the same problem before?
I have stuck in this for days.

Below is my Server-side code

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
import mysql from "mysql2";
import cors from "cors";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import session from "express-session";
import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy } from "passport-local";
import flash from "connect-flash";
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "MEMBERSECRETINFO",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60, sameSite: "none" },
  })
);
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
  console.log("serializeUser:", user.id);
  cb(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
  memberDb.query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ?", [id], (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }
    const user = result[0];
    console.log(user);
    if (user) {
      console.log("deserializeUser: ", user);
      cb(null, user);
    }
  });
});

app.get("/membership", (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "You have logged in!" });
  } else {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "You haven't logged in yet!" });
  }

app.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureMessage: true,
    keepSessionInfo: true,
    failureFlash: true,
  }),
  function (req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated) {
      // console.log(req.user);
      res.cookie("test cookie", req.session.cookie, {
        maxAge: 60000,
        httpOnly: true,
      });
      req.session.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        }
        res.redirect("/membership");
      });
    } else {
      res.send({ message });
    }
  }
);

passport.use(
  new Strategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    function verify(req, email, password, cb) {
      try {
        memberDb.query(
          "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = ?",
          [email],
          (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
              return cb(err);
            }
            const user = result[0];
            if (!user) {
              return cb(null, false);
            }
            const storedHashedPassword = user.password;
            bcrypt.compare(password, storedHashedPassword, (err, result) => {
              if (err) {
                return cb(err);
              } else {
                if (result) {
                  return cb(null, user);
                } else {
                  req.session.save((err) => {
                    if (err) {
                      return cb(err);
                    }
                    return cb(null, false, {
                      message: "Invalid username or password",
                    });
                  });
                }
              }
            });
          }
        );
      } catch (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Below is my Client-side code

```
Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5174/login", {
      email: signinInfo.email,
      password: signinInfo.password,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.user) {
          setLoginStatus(response.data.user);
          // navigate("/membership");
        } else if (response.data.messages != "Missing credentials") {
          setLoginStatus(response.data.messages);
        } else {
          setLoginStatus("You haven't filled your Email/Password");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
      });
  };
```

Thank you in advanve.
Wish you have a good day without facing any bug.